# Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test with Jest and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I'm trying to implement database population by using a migration function. The code works perfectly, it saves all the data into the database, but the test for the function is failing, and now I would like to know why?

I'm getting the "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms" error for this particular test. I've written 166 tests for this app and all of them are passing.

Here is the function I want to test:

```
    const doMigration = async ({ model, data }) => {
        await model.collection.insertMany(data)
    }
```

And here is the test:

```
    const { Amodel } = require('../../../models/Amodel')
    const { doMigration } = require('../../../database/migrations')

    describe('Database Population', () => {
        it ('Should populate the database using migrations', async () => {
            const data = [{ name: 'A' }, { name: 'B' }]
            const model = Amodel
            const migration = { name: 'Amodel', model, data }

            await doMigration(migration)

            const countAfter = await Amodel.count()
            expect(countAfter).toBe(2)
        })
    })
```

In this test I simply import the function, the model and create a migration object that then is passed to the function.

What did I try?

1. Tried using just the countAfter without using the doMigration function, and it still generates the same timeout error.
2. Tried increasing the time for this test to 30000, failed with error saying that the mongodb time exceeded the 10000 ms.

Here is the github repository: https://github.com/Elvissamir/Fullrvmovies

What is happening, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 6):

The problem was the way the mongodb connection was handled. When testing, the app created a connection to the db on startup, and then the jest tests used that connection, that caused some issues.

The solution was to connect to the database on startup only if the environment is set to testing, otherwise the connection will be handled by each set of tests.

In each set I added a beforeAll and afterAll to open and close the connection to the database.

Hope it helps anyone that finds the same problem or has similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The orientation is that the message reflect the actual reason, So i recommand to follow the following steps:

1. use the following code to check mongo state:

   ```
   const { MongoMemoryServer } = require("mongodb-memory-server");
   const mongoose = require("mongoose");

   (async () => {
    mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    const mongoUri = mongod.getUri();

    await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }).then((result) => {
     console.log(result.connection.readyState)  
     console.log(result.connection.host)
    }).catch((err) => {

    });;
   })();
   ```
2. if you are using mongodb-memory-server add "testTimeout" attribute:

   ```
   "jest": {
   "preset": "ts-jest",
   "testEnvironment": "node",
   "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
       "./src/test/setup.ts"
    ],
   "testTimeout": 15000
   },
   ```
3. If all above still huppens check the time-out of all inter-test operation